# Bash variable name expansion in a loop

Tags: bash

I have several variables that have the name format of:

```
var0_name
var1_name
var2_name
```

And I want to be able to loop thru them in a manner like this:

```
for i in {0..2}
do
  echo "My variable name = " ${var[i]_name}
done
```

I have tried several different ways to get this expansion to work but have had no luck so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `${!prefix*}` expansion in `bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash

var0_name=xyz
var1_name=asdf
var2_name=zx

for v in ${!var*}; do
    echo "My variable name = $v"
    # echo "Variable '$v' has the value of '${!v}'"
done
```

or equivalently, by replacing the `for` loop with:

```
printf 'My variable name = %s\n' ${!var*}
```

---

You may also consider reading the [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) for detailed information on all forms of parameter expansions in `bash`, including those that are used in the answer as well.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. That works as desired to expand the variable name but now how do I use that to also get the value of that variable using `$v`?

Comment: @phydeauxman The `!` introduces a level of indirection: `${!v}`. Remove the `#` before `echo` in the updated answer and examine the output.

Comment: Is there a method of indirect expansion that will work on the end of variable names? What if I had several variables that were of the format: `myvar1_var` , `myvar2_var`, `myvar3_var`. Is there something like ${!*_var} that do an indirect expansion of each of these variables?

Comment: @phydeauxman As far as I know, there is no such a direct method, but something like that could be used to list variable names ending with `_var`:  `(set -o posix ; set) | sed -n '/_var=/s/=.*//p'`